# Getting error wihle importing Icons for the ToolbarAndroid

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to use the react-native's `ToolbarAndroid` from [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons)'s `Icon.ToolbarAndroid`. But I am getting this error:

> RNVectorIconsModule not available, did you properly integrate the module?

I have installed `rnpm` also did `rnpm link`, which was completed successfully.

And I think I have properly integrated the module, because this code works where I get the icons from `react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons`:

**(WORKING)**

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

const searchIcon = (<Icon name="md-search" size={30} color="#4F8EF7" />)
const menuIcon =  (<Icon name="md-menu" size={30} color="#4F8EF7" />)
const notificationIcon =  (<Icon name="md-notifications-outline" size={30} color="#4F8EF7" />)

export default class Header extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>{searchIcon}</Text>
                <Text>{menuIcon}</Text>
                <Text>{notificationIcon}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

But this code doesn't work:

**(NOT WORKING)**

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

export default class Header extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <Icon.ToolbarAndroid
                title="Home"
                titleColor="white"
                navIconName="md-search"
                actions={[
                    { title: 'Settings', iconName: 'md-menu', iconSize: 30, show: 'always' },
                    { title: 'Follow me on Twitter', iconName: 'md-notifications-outline', iconColor: "#4099FF", show: 'ifRoom' },
                ]}
                overflowIconName="md-more"
            />
        )
    }
}
```

I am very new to react-native so I may be doing something wrong? Will you please help me figure it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you have probably seen (I also saw your message on [Github](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/260)), the complete instructions are here: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#integrating-library-for-getimagesource-and-toolbarandroid-support

I had the same issue as yours. By completing the instructions, I successfully manage to make it work.

I will not duplicate the instructions but to clarify:

1) Edit `android/settings.gradle`
2) Edit `android/app/build.gradle`
3) Edit your `MainApplication.java`